# While trying to create entity data model, I get authorization exception

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-data-model

I set up my visual studio to always run as administrator.
When I create a new Entity Data Model, and try to point to the data source to a specific database, I get the error "Login failed.  Log in is from an untrusted domain...."

I think that since I set VS up to run under administrator, Administrator needs access to at least one database, so I set that up as well.

But I am still getting the same issues.

See screenshots.
[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with Microsoft.
The server name dropdown box doesn't always list the right servers.
It was listing a server that did not exist.
Somehow, it gets this information, from somewhere--I don't exactly know how--but I did have the posted server name on a different machine at one point in time.
I clicked on the ddl and picked the first one, assuming it found my server, but in fact the server did not exist.
I had to copy paste this in:  DESKTOP-DLASSIT\SQLEXPRESS
Because that was the real name of my server.
Then, it worked...